# Associate Lists and Tasks in Meteor todo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm building the todo application from the Meteor tutorial and continue it. I'm building some lists based on the task model, but I don't know how to join them and say when I click on one list, I want all the tasks from this one.

For the moment, I have the Tasks.js with:

```
    'tasks.insert'(text, privacy, priority, listId) {
        ...

        Tasks.insert({
            text,

            listId: listId,

            owner: this.userId,
            username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
        });
    },
```

Body.js

```
   Template.body.events({
      'submit .new-task' (event) {
           event.preventDefault();

    const listId = ???

    const target = event.target;
    const text = target.text.value;
    ...
    Meteor.call('tasks.insert', text, privacy, priority, listId);
    ...
},
```

And then where I display it:

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks() {
        const instance = Template.instance();

        if (instance.state.get('hideCompleted')) {
            return Tasks.find({ checked: { $ne: true } }, { sort: Session.get("sort_order") });
        }
        return Tasks.find({}, { sort: Session.get("sort_order")});
    },

    lists() {
        return Lists.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
    },
```

I my body.html, I just display each items (lists and tasks) separately. But the problem is I don't know how to make the relation between both ...

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Help me understand what you're trying to do better. What do you mean by "when I click on one list, I want all the tasks from this one"?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood :) In fact in a left sidebar I have my list items, then in the container, I have the tasks. I would like associate the tasks to some lists, and display the tasks owned by the list I select only. (click on the list and display the tasks associate to this list) thanks

Comment: I think I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are already using Session. Basically, you will use a Session variable that tracks what the list the user has selected, and then filter your tasks with that variable.

In your body, where you're displaying your list names, add the list's id as an HTML attribute:

```
{{#each lists}}
  <a href='#' class='list-name' data-id='{{this._id}}'>
    {{this.name}}
  </a>
{{/each}}
```

Add an event for clicking on a list name that saves its id to a Session variable:

```
Template.body.events({
  'click .list-name' (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    Session.set('listId', event.currentTarget.attr('data-id'))
  }
})
```

In your `tasks` helper, filter your query using the Session variable:

```
return Tasks.find(
  { listId: Session.get('listId') },
  { sort: Session.get("sort_order") }
);
```

Let me know if anything could be more clear.

Comment: Can I use this Session var to add a class of the selected list item and also get a counter of tasks or I have to use a new entry in collection for each ? Thanks

Comment: I'm happy to help, and I think I understand what the issue is, but it would probably be best for you to just create another Stack Overflow question so we can keep this page clean. You should probably delete your answer below - answers are not for asking questions.